# How do I tell EF to ignore columns from my database?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm building my EF (v4.0.30319) data model from my SQL Server database. Each table has `Created` and `Updated` fields populated via database triggers.

This database is the backend of a ASP.NET Web API application and I recently discovered a problem. The problem is, since the `Created` and `Updated` fields are not populated in the model passed into the api endpoint, they are written to the database as `NULL`. This overwrites any values already in the database for those properties.

I discovered I can edit the EF data model and just delete those two columns from the entity. It works and the datetimes are not overwritten with `NULL`. But this leads to another, less serious but more annoying, problem... my data model has a bunch of tables that contain these properties and all the tables need to be updated by removing these two columns.

Is there a way to tell EF to ignore certain columns in entities across the entire data model without manually deleting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  Generating the model from the database is going to always create all of the fields from the database table. Well, as long as it has a primary key it will.

It is possible to only update the fields that you want i.e. don't include the "Created" and "Updated" fields in your create and update methods.  I'd have to say though, that I'd think it'd be better if those fields didn't even exist on the model at that point.  You may at one point see those fields on the model and not remember that they won't get persisted to the DB.

You may want to look into just inserting the datetimes into those fields when you call your create() and update() methods. Then you could just ditch the triggers.  You'd obviously want to use a class library for all of your database operations so this functionality would be in one place.  To keep it nice and neat, you know?