# Entity Framework Core: Global select filter

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF Core you can add [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to exclude data that fulfill some condition. I was wondering if the "same" exists for globally selecting properties of entities, e.g. to globally exclude sensitive information from `ApplicationUser` from [.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)?

E.g. something like this:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasSelectFilter(u => new ApplicationUser {
    Id = u.Id,
    Email = u.Email,
    ...
});
```

EDIT: I just found that you can use 
`builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(u => u.PasswordHash);`
when configuring relations with the FluentAPI. However, it seems to create problems within Identity.

[Ignore properties in data model while keeping them in EF Core migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057856/ignore-properties-in-data-model-while-keeping-them-in-ef-core-migrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by default nothing supports it in EF Core.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows using the filter as a Global select filter as well.

Example:

```
QueryFilterManager.Filter<Customer>(c => c.Select(x => new Customer() { CustomerId = x.CustomerId, Name = x.Name }));

// ...code...

var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
```

Online Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wArKog